# Word 2016 Table of Contents in two columns

Tags: microsoft-word, format, table-of-contents, title

I want to get my table of contents onto a single page.
I can do this most easily by having the ToC in a section defined as newspaper column layout.
I now have two issues

- How do I stop/hide the ToC heading (Contents or Table of Contents). I
  want it to span both columns so I'll add it manually
- How do I change the default line spacing (to single with 0pt padding above or below)
  TFAI

Answer (score 0):

See http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AddIns
For a simple ToC add in that does not have a title like "Contents"

It also has a whole bunch of other useful Word stuff

Comment: A special add-in isn't required. By default, if you insert a Custom TOC (References > Table of Contents > Custom Table of Contents), no heading is added.

Comment: And so it seems. Thank you for that elegant solution